# fullpage.js - After resposive is triggered, jQuery.position() and .offset() still return 0,0

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js, scrollmagic

Trying to use ScrollMagic with fullpage.js - I have searched and only found that it is suggested to use `scrollBar: true` or `autoScrolling: false` to enable jQuery positioning or offsets, however, upon responsive (which turns the page into a normal scrolling site), the position still remains at that (0,0) position.

This seems a bit confusing, as in my mind, if I say:

`autoScrolling: true,`

but

`responsiveWidth: 991`

and, via the documentation:

> **A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used** under the defined width in pixels ... For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's width is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.

So why wouldn't my `$('.fp-section').position()` work after checking for Responsive in `afterResponsive(isResponsive)`?

example:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/schnoodly/pen/QxpZXx)

```js
jQuery('#main').fullpage({
  //Navigation
  lockAnchors: false,
  navigation: true,
  navigationPosition: 'left',
  showActiveTooltip: false,
  slidesNavigation: false,

  //Scrolling
  scrollingSpeed: 700,
  autoScrolling: true,
  fitToSection: false,
  fitToSectionDelay: null,
  scrollBar: false,
  easingcss3: 'ease',
  scrollHorizontally: true,
  offsetSections: false,
  resetSliders: false,
  touchSensitivity: 15,
  normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
  bigSectionsDestination: 'top',
  dragAndMove: 'fingersonly',

  //Accessibility
  keyboardScrolling: true,
  animateAnchor: true,
  recordHistory: false,

  //Design
  sectionsColor: ['#ccc', 'black', '#ccc'],
  responsiveWidth: 991,

  //Custom selectors
  sectionSelector: '.section',
  lazyLoading: true,
  afterResponsive: function(isResponsive) {
    var scene = [];
    var parallaxTween = [];
    var box = jQuery('.moveme');
    var parallax = new TimelineMax();
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: .5,
        duration: window.innerHeight + 50
      }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      var yPer = -100;
      var yEnd = 100;
      //reset scene on responsive
      if (scene[i])
        scene[i].destroy(true);
      parallaxTween[i] = null;
      scene[i] = null;

      console.log(box.closest('.section').position());

      parallaxTween[i] = parallax.fromTo(jQuery('.container').eq(i), 1, {
        yPercent: yPer
      }, {
        yPercent: yEnd,
        ease: Linear.easeNone
      }, 0);

      scene[i] = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: jQuery(box[i]).closest('.section'),
        })
        .setTween(parallaxTween[i])
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.moveme {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main class="site-main fullpage-wrapper" id="main" role="main" style="height: 100%; position: relative; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: none;">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="moveme">i should move
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="moveme">i should move
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="moveme">i should move
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/jquery.ScrollMagic.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1295227/animation.gsap.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1295227/debug.addIndicators.js'></script>
```

Comment: How about creating an example to help people help you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I have added an example.

Comment: I can see the last of the blue boxes moving as expected when scrolling. 
Something's wrong with your code, but definitely not with fullPage.js.

Comment: And here's the proff:
https://jsfiddle.net/1kyuL4em/64/

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks for the pointer and response, I was more thinking about there being a strange interaction between scrollmagic and fullpage.js, but I was just hoping to get a pointer as to why, even in responsive, the position of a nested element returns 0? I didn't mention this, but if you make the box only one element, (i.e. a div with text, not a div with a P) it WILL return proper position.

Comment: Do the `onleave` type of events still work in responsive? Maybe I can just use that instead? edit: additionally, they all move at once on the last section only, despite indicators showing correct positions in the codepen.